# Database is locked. insert operation

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, locked

I have no idea what to do anymore with this code. I did review the opening and closing of my connections and I think all connections are okay.

I have to tables here that I'm trying to insert data. The `imf` table and the `imf_products` table. My goal is as soon as I have inserted data to my `imf` table I should insert data again to `my imf_products`.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Natasha_POS
{
    public partial class m2 : Form
    {
        public SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
        public m2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (combo_compname.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify the company name.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (combo_artname.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify the product name.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (combo_color.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify the product color.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (combo_size.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify the product size.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (textBox8.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify the product price.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (box_numeric.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify the number of products you're acquiring.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                dGrid.Rows.Add(combo_artname.Text,
                                combo_color.Text,
                                combo_size.Text,
                               Convert.ToInt32(box_numeric.Value),
                                Convert.ToInt32( textBox8.Text),
                                combo_discount.Text,"","",
                                Convert.ToInt32(combo_artname.SelectedValue),
                                Convert.ToInt32(combo_color.SelectedValue),
                                Convert.ToInt32(combo_size.SelectedValue),
                                Convert.ToInt32(combo_discount.SelectedValue)
                                );

                ////new
                combo_compname.Text = "--Select Company--";
                combo_cat.Text = "--Select Category--";
                combo_artname.Text = "--Select Product--";
                combo_color.Text = "--Select Color--";
                combo_size.Text = "--Select Size--";
                textBox8.Clear();
                box_numeric.Value = 0;
                combo_custno.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void m2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker.Enabled = false;
            box_custname.Text = null;

            SQLiteConnection conn1 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn1.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = conn1.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from customer";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.Fill(dt);
            combo_custno.DataSource = dt;
            combo_custno.ValueMember = "cp_id";
            combo_custno.DisplayMember = "customer_no";
            combo_custno.Text = "--Select Customer--";

            /*IList<string> CustNo = new List<string>(); 
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                CustNo.Add(row.Field<string>("cp_id"));
            }
            combo_custno.Items.AddRange(CustNo.ToArray<string>());
            combo_custno.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            combo_custno.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems; */

            conn1.Close();

            SQLiteConnection conn2 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            conn2.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand();

            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * from company";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2);

            adapter2.Fill(dt2);
            combo_compname.DataSource = dt2;
            combo_compname.ValueMember = "company_id";
            combo_compname.DisplayMember = "company_name";
            combo_compname.Text = "--Select Company--";

            conn2.Close();

            SQLiteConnection conn3 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            conn3.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd3 = conn3.CreateCommand();

            cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM category";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter3 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd3);

            adapter3.Fill(dt3);
            combo_cat.DataSource = dt3;
            combo_cat.ValueMember = "category_id";
            combo_cat.DisplayMember = "category_name";
            combo_cat.Text = "--Select Category--";
            conn3.Close();

            SQLiteConnection conn4 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
            conn4.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd4 = conn4.CreateCommand();

            cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM colors";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter4 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd4);

            adapter4.Fill(dt4);
            combo_color.DataSource = dt4;
            combo_color.ValueMember = "color_id";
            combo_color.DisplayMember = "color_name";
            combo_color.Text = "--Select Color--";
            conn4.Close();

            SQLiteConnection conn5 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
            conn5.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd5 = conn5.CreateCommand();

            cmd5.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM discount";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter5 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd5);

            adapter5.Fill(dt5);
            combo_discount.DataSource = dt5;
            combo_discount.ValueMember = "discount_id";
            combo_discount.DisplayMember = "discount_name";
            combo_discount.Text = "";
            conn5.Close();

            //this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void combo_custno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // int x = Convert.ToInt32(combo_custno.Text);

           //////////textboxes
           SQLiteConnection conn4 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
           DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
           conn4.Open();
           SQLiteCommand cmd4 = conn4.CreateCommand();

           cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer where cp_id = '" + combo_custno.SelectedValue + "'";
           SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
           if (dr.Read())
           {
               //string fname = Convert.ToString(dr["firstname"]);
               //string mname = Convert.ToString(dr["firstname"]);
               box_custname.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["firstname"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(dr["middlename"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(dr["lastname"]);
               box_mse.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["msediscount"]);
               box_nfc.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["nfcdiscount"]);
               box_rating.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["rating"]);
               box_avcredline.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["available_credit_line"]);
           }
           conn4.Close();

        }

        private void combo_cat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //int x = Convert.ToInt32(combo_cat.Text);

            SQLiteConnection conn2 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            conn2.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand();

            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM product where category_id = '" + combo_cat.SelectedValue+ "'";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2);

            adapter2.Fill(dt2);
            combo_artname.DataSource = dt2;
            combo_artname.ValueMember = "product_id";
            combo_artname.DisplayMember = "product_name";
            combo_artname.Text = "--Select Product--";
            conn2.Close();

            SQLiteConnection conn3 = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db");
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            conn3.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd3 = conn3.CreateCommand();

            cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM size where category_id = '" + combo_cat.SelectedValue + "'";
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter3 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd3);

            adapter3.Fill(dt3);
            combo_size.DataSource = dt3;
            combo_size.ValueMember = "size_id";
            combo_size.DisplayMember = "size_name";
            combo_size.Text = "--Select Size--";
            conn3.Close();

        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void inserttoSO(string custno)
        {

            con.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custno", combo_custno.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker.Value);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", box_commment.Text);
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sales_order (customer_no,date) VALUES (@custno,@date)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //inserttoSO(combo_custno.Text);
            var results = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to generate this inventory report?",
                                    "Inventory report is successfully made.",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                    MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (results == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                inserttoSO(combo_custno.Text);

                string StrQuery = "";

                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=default.db"))
                    {
                        using (SQLiteCommand cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand())
                        {
                            cmd1.Connection = conn;
                            conn.Open();

                        for (int i = 0; i < dGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            /*"INSERT INTO imf_products(imf_id, company_id,product_id, color_id,size_id,price,qty) VALUES  (1,1,1,1,1,1,1)";*/
                            //(SELECT max(imf_id) FROM imf) StrQuery
                            cmd1.CommandText =
                                "INSERT INTO orders(salesorder_id, product_id, quantity,price,cash, discount_id) VALUES ((SELECT max(salesorder_id) FROM sales_order),'"
                                + dGrid.Rows[i].Cells["product_id"].Value + "', '" + dGrid.Rows[i].Cells["qty"].Value + "', '"
                                + dGrid.Rows[i].Cells["price"].Value + "', '" + dGrid.Rows[i].Cells["cash"].Value + "', '"
                                + dGrid.Rows[i].Cells["discount_id"].Value  + "')";
                            // cmd.CommandText = StrQuery;
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Sales report is successfully made.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

                        }
                       // conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
            }
            else
            { MessageBox.Show("Inventory report is not made.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk); }

        }

        private void textBox8_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                    && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            //check if '.' , ',' pressed
            char sepratorChar = 's';
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ',')
            {
                // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept
                if (textBox8.Text.Length == 0) e.Handled = true;
                // check if it's in the beginning of text not accept
                if (textBox8.SelectionStart == 0) e.Handled = true;
                // check if there is already exist a '.' , ','
                if (alreadyExist(textBox8.Text, ref sepratorChar)) e.Handled = true;
                //check if '.' or ',' is in middle of a number and after it is not a number greater than 99
                if (textBox8.SelectionStart != textBox8.Text.Length && e.Handled == false)
                {
                    // '.' or ',' is in the middle
                    string AfterDotString = textBox8.Text.Substring(textBox8.SelectionStart);

                    if (AfterDotString.Length > 2)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //check if a number pressed

            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                //check if a coma or dot exist
                if (alreadyExist(textBox8.Text, ref sepratorChar))
                {
                    int sepratorPosition = textBox8.Text.IndexOf(sepratorChar);
                    string afterSepratorString = textBox8.Text.Substring(sepratorPosition + 1);
                    if (textBox8.SelectionStart > sepratorPosition && afterSepratorString.Length > 1)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        private bool alreadyExist(string _text, ref char KeyChar)
        {
            if (_text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                KeyChar = '.';
                return true;
            }
            if (_text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
            {
                KeyChar = ',';
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inserttoSO(combo_custno.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using twenty different connections to the same database?

Comment: im a newbie :(( pls help me :(

Comment: Just use a single connection (`con`).